# div after last li get merged in it in ie

Tags: css, xhtml

i have following xhtml, i have to add div after last li in ul. Every browser is displaying list correctly except ie 6

```
<ul>

  <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
  <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
  <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
  <li>some div here</li>
  <div class="more">add nore</div> 

</ul>
```

but div defined at last is getting merged into last li and become its part. its css is as follow

```
ul{ border:1px solid #C9C9C9; list-style:none;  }
ul li{ border:1px solid #C9C9C9; display:inline-block; }
ul li .content{ border:0px solid; float:left; }
.more{ border:1px solid #D7D7D7; text-align:center; width:600px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
    <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
    <li><div class="content">some div here</div></li>
    <li>some div here</li>
 </ul>
    <div class="more">add nore</div>
```

You [can't have a non-`<li>` element as a child of a `<ul>`](http://learningforlife.fsu.edu/webmaster/references/xhtml/tags/list/ul.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `clear:both` and `overflow:hidden` to the div css:

```
.more{
   border:1px solid #D7D7D7;
   text-align:center;
   width:600px;
   clear:both;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```